# Button wrapping content wrongly with drawable inside

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-button

While using an android button, I keep coming back to the same problem... When I try to add a drawable to a button, the button keeps wrongly framing the drawable.

The button code:

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/cancel_directions_button_v2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableBottom="@drawable/i_close"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/info_directions_textview"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_marginBottom="26sp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        />
```

Photo:
[image]

Comment: please can you provide more insight. do you mean that the X drawable is not positioned correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using ImageButton instead.

```
<ImageButton
    .
    .
    .
    android:src="@android:drawable/i_close" />
```